# Scroll function not firing at the location I am wanting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, scroll

I have a window scroll function that I am trying to dial in. Initially, I attempted to do with with waypoints, but couldn't figure it out.

My issue is my function is firing too early and not in the location I am wanting it to. It fires when the bottom of the screen gets to the main container this is all in, `#home-info`. The issue I have with this is if someone is scrolling slow they never see the animation. Ideally I want the function to fire when it gets to `#info-container`, the container with the animated objects in it.

What am I doing wrong that is not allowing this to happen or is there a better way to do this?

[Fiddle. See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/nufzypLc/)

```
function boxes() {
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {

    var top, green, yellow, red;

    top = this.scrollY;

    green   = document.querySelector("#green"),
    yellow  = document.querySelector("#yellow"),
    red     = document.querySelector("#red");

    if(top > 100){
      green.classList.add("green", "active");
      yellow.classList.add("yellow", "active");
      red.classList.add("red", "active");
    }
}, false);
}
setTimeout(boxes,1200);


<div id="home-info">
        <div id="home-info-container">
            <div id="home-info-container">
                <div id="home-info-container-description">
                    <div id="home-info-container-title">THE <span class="yellow-color sansbold">LEADING</span> PROVIDER FOR<br> DEMOLITION & WRECKING</div>
                    <div id="home-info-description">The Eslich Wrecking Company has been recognized as a leader in the demolition field for over 60 years. Over that time span, we have gained both the experience and reputation for doing quality work in an expedient, safe and cost efficient manner. Our track record proves that Eslich Wrecking has the people, equipment and know-how to tackle even the most complex situations and the most demanding jobs. This includes the capability to bond any project when necessary and to carry general liability, auto, and pollution insurance up to 10 million.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
<section id="info">
  <article id="info-container">
    <a href="projects">
      <div id="green" class="box">
        <div class="info-box-title">PROJECT AFTER PROJECT</div>
        <div class="info-box-description">Over 60 years of accumulated projects.</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="about">
      <div id="yellow" class="box">
        <div class="info-box-title">YEARS OF DEMOLITION HISTORY</div>
        <div class="info-box-description">Find out about - The Eslich Wrecking Company.</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="contact">
      <div id="red" class="box">
        <div class="info-box-title">GET IN TOUCH WITH US</div>
        <div class="info-box-description">Contact us for more information.</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </article>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: You're starting the animation whenever `top > 100`. Your `#info-container` is way below that. Why 100? And what's with the `setTimeout`?

Comment: @DavidHedlund I've tried using different values than 100, but in reality I want it to be set for the container and not a pixel. I added `setTimeout` to delay the function, somewhat as a bandaid until I get this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to hardcode your scrollbar position. The position at which your object becomes visible depends on the height of the view port, but more importantly on how much content you have above the target element.

Define a variable target with something like the following:

```
var target = $('#info-container').offset().top;
if(top >= target) {
   // start animation
}
```

Also note that scroll *top* tells you nothing of what is in your view port, if you don't also look at the *height* of your window. In the condition above, use something like

```
var top = this.scrollY + $(window).height();
```

This will give you a condition that evaluates to true as soon as `#info-container` is scrolled into view. Depending on your needs, you may want your `target` to also include the `$('#info-container').height()`, if you want the scroll to start once the *entire* `#info-container` is in view.

Comment: Thanks!  I can't seem to get `.height()` to work. I did the same as you did `var target = $('#info-container').height();`. It loads right when the container is in view, just like the other.

Comment: @Becky: Yes, `offset().top` is where the element starts, relative to the document, and `height()` is its height. If you want to make sure that the *entire* element is scrolled into view, you want your threshold to be top plus height, not just height.

Comment: I'm not sure what I am doing wrong now. `var target = $('#info-container').offset().top.height();`

Comment: @Becky: `$('#info-container').offset().top` gives you an integer, such as `150`. The integer no longer has any information about the fact that it is the top position of an element; only you know that. It doesn't have a `height` function - `150.height()` doesn't make any sense. `$('#info-container')` is a jQuery reference to an element. This has a `height` function. `$('#info-container').height()` gives you another integer. Add those two to get `top + height`, i.e. the bottom position of the element.